Angular sharing data between components queried by apollo angular
I have a query that pulls in data from my database using appollo-angular. What would be the best practise way to share this data between componenets. I saw that it was mentioned using a shared service and subscribing in each component. Would this method take into account data updates as currently I'm querying and grabbing the data again every single time:
Inside service:
private data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
currentData = this.data.asObservable();
  
    getDataFromDB(): Observable<any> {
      return this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
        query: DataQuery,
      }).valueChanges.pipe(
        tap((res: any) => {
        this.dataFromDB.next(res.data.dataFromDB);
      })
      );
     }

Inside componenet1:
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.currentData.subscribe(queryData => {
  this.data = queryData;
});
}

It was previously querying the data everytime the component was loaded but I'm looking to see how to optimize this and have tried setting up a service but not sure If I'm approaching it correctly
